# Changing order of columns on different screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

basically what I'm trying to achieve using bootstrap is something like this 
(https://ibb.co/mBB9P6P). When it's resized to smaller screens it should like 
(https://ibb.co/0XnDy2S). Of course with the code I'm using, what happens is that second image goes behind second paragraph

My idea was using Bootstrap's order-first and order-last classes to achieve this and while it works for mobile, on desktop both pictures are on left. What I thought would work was removing a class from a div on different media query but I'm not sure if that's even an option.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="img1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="img1.png">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have this tagged as Bootstrap 3. If you are using Bootstrap 4, which uses `flex` you can use the `order` property. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696662/css-flexbox-for-2-column-and-3-column-on-desktop-and-mobile-wrap

Comment: Seems like this will solve my problem, I'll give it a go soon, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, then you can take advantage of its `flex` based layout and use the `order` property. Here is an example:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-9 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    order: 1;
  }
}

img {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/2mwxeor5/1/

Comment: Wow, amazing! Exactly what I wanted. Cheers mate!

Comment: @PetarBrković Awesome! If you would upvote the answer and mark it as accepted, that would help future visitors. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap divides the screen up into 12 column grid. If you choose md-3 then you will get four cols max going across. You can specify multiple column formats all in the class attribute. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ Hope this helps.

Comment: What Evan's saying is your image `div` tags should be `col-md-3 col-sm-12` and your text `div` tags should be `col-md-9 col-sm-12`. This will make images take up 3/12 on medium+ screens and 12/12 on small screens, and text will take up 9/12 on medium+ screens and 12/12 on small screens.

Comment: Right, thanks for that information! The thing is it doesn't really quite answer my question about possibility of changing orders on different screens

Answer (score -1):

Drop Bootstrap (it will cause more issues anyway) and use flexbox. The order property will help you.

Comment: Why would Bootstrap cause more issues? It's the framework the OP is working in. Bootstrap 4 is flexbox based.