# CSS FlexBox | Reordering Elements in Mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn CSS Flexbox and found an impediment.

I have content that displays right and left on desktop screen sizes and for mobile, I have `flex-direction: column`

See the visual bellow:

Desktop:
[image]

Mobile:
[image]

This is the code to accomplish such:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">
      <div class="a">a</div>
      <div class="b">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box2">
       <div class="c">c</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

These are the flexbox styles:

```
.box {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  height: 50%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .box {
     height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

When in mobile, how can I order the following divs to be displayed in columns (as is)  **however** on the following order:

a

c

d

**b**

I can't seem to find a solution for that unfortunately.

I have a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/tonkihonks/pen/MREjZN) the CSS lines that matter are from line 162 onward.

Comment: Using only CSS, I think your content should be at the same level for you to be able to use `order` with your use case, right now they are trapped inside the parent `div.box`.

Comment: Thank you Nuri. Could you please provide an answer example?

Comment: My bad, look at the answer of Temani Afif.

Comment: @NuriKatsuki I think you still have a valid point, because of lack of support in any IE/Edge version and inaccessibility issues with other major browsers, but `display: contents` is pretty cool.

Comment: @NullisTrue in the event that you need support for Edge, you can check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477305/changing-order-of-columns-on-different-screens/55481591#55481591

Comment: You need a css only solution or tweaking the html a bit would be also an option?

Comment: @ezakto Both or either way would work as long as I can accomplish the trick without changing what I previously got on desktop layout wise. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) on the `.box` element then you will be able to use order on the inner elements:

```css
.box {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background:blue;
}

.a,.b,.c,.d {
  height: 50%;
  border:2px solid;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box {
    display:contents;
  }
  .b {
    order:2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="d">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear **as if they were direct children of the element's parent**, ignoring the element itself. This can be useful **when a wrapper element should be ignored** when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

---

If you are open to change the html you can do it like below:

```css
.container > * {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  border:2px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background:blue;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.a,.b,.c,.d {
  height: 50%;
  width:50%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .a,.b,.c,.d {
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
  }
  .b {
    order:2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
```

And with CSS grid:

```css
.container > * {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:2px solid;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:  
    'a b'
    'c d';
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background:blue;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.a {
  grid-area:a;
}
.b {
  grid-area:b;
}
.c {
  grid-area:c;
}
.d {
  grid-area:d;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
   grid-template-areas:  
    'a'
    'c' 
    'd'
    'b';
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nuri Katsuki's comment is right. If the "abcd" divs are on the same level, you can use CSS `order` property to achieve the order you want on mobile.

Also, the `flex-wrap: wrap` makes the children flow into columns on desktop query

I've edited your sample to illustrate it:

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  width: 100vw;
  
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.a { background:#e67e22;}
.b { background:#e74c3c;}
.c { background:#9b59b6;}
.d { background:#34495e;}


.a, .b, .c, .d {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
  }
  .a, .b, .c, .d { width: 100%; }
  .b {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Some default styles to make each box visible */
html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  width: 100vw;
  
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a { background:#e67e22;}
.b { background:#e74c3c;}
.c { background:#9b59b6;}
.d { background:#34495e;}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
  }
  .a, .b, .c, .d { width: 100%; }
  .b {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you order your divs as `.a` & `.c` in `.box1` and `.c` & `.d` in .box 2, you can use column in `.container` for desktop, and column in `.box` in mobile + order within `.box2`:

```css
.box {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex; /* <-- */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column; /* <-- */
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  height: 50%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .box {
    height: 50vh;
    flex-direction: column; /* <-- */
  }

  .box2 .d {
    order: 0; /* <-- */
  }
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">
      <div class="a">a</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box2">
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```